# How to improve performance of multiple "or" in Case statement

Tags: sql, performance, google-bigquery, case

I am realizing that a particular subquery is killing performance and curious is there is a better way to write such a Case statement. I am trying to use "=" when possible but often need the "like" statement. My questions are:

If column_a = 1, will this statement return a value immediately, or will it still read through the subsequent "or" statements?

```
case 

  when column_a = 1 
    or column_b like '%string a%'
    or column_b like '%string b%'
    or column_b like '%string c%'
  then 'Return A'

  when column_a = 2 
    or column_b like '%string d%'
    or column_b like '%string e%'
    or column_b like '%string f%'
  then 'Return B'
.
.
.
  else 'Return Z'
end
```

Is it better to have a long list of "or" as shown, or better to put each check in its own case statement, i.e.

```
case 

  when column_a = 1 
  then 'Return A'

  when column_b like '%string a%' 
  then 'Return A'

  when column_b like '%string b%'
  then 'Return A'
.
.
.
```

Comment: Maybe this video can help you: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UueWySREWvk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If column_a = 1, will this statement return a value immediately, or will it still read through the subsequent "or" statements?

The statement will return result immediately without evaluating rest of ORs

> Is it better to have a long list of "or" as shown, or better to put each check in its own case statement

I would recommend former  - to at least keep it readable

Another option to rewrite multiple LIKEs statement is to use

```
REGEXP_CONTAINS(column_b, r'string a|string b|string c')
```

Comment: . . Do you have a reference for your first answer?  In general, databases reserve the right to rearrange expressions.  I would expect the `=` to be evaluated first, but I don't know that BigQuery guarantees it.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - :o) good point! No, I don't have any reference for that my statement. It is more empirical and based on my own experience with this type of expressions in the BigQuery. I hope, if i am totally wrong, someone from BigQuery Team will correct me here, for benefits of all of us who love BigQuery :o)

Comment: . . Empirically, I think you are correct.  I just don't think it is mandated by the product (I would be surprised if it is).